# How to get child table rows using parent table ID?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables: Organization(Parent) and Department(Child).

There is One to Many relationship, and is mentioned in Organization table only.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_STD_ORGANIZATION")
public class Organization implements Serializable  {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name="FLD_ORG_ID")
  private Long organizationId;

  @Column(name="FLD_ORG_NAME")
  private String orgName;

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
  private java.util.List<Department> listOfDepartMents = new java.util.ArrayList<Department>();
}
```

Below is Department Class:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="TBL_STD_DEPARTMENT")
    public class Department implements Serializable { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "FLD_DEPARTMENT_ID")
    private Long departmentId;

    @Column(name = "FLD_DEPARTMENT_NAME")
    private String departmentName;
    }
```

I wrote relationship in Parent table, because of it hibernate creates third table.
Now, I have to retrieve departments start with "sa" keyword and in specific organization.
So I want the HQL or SQL query query. I am not getting it how to write such complex query.
Any suggestions?

Comment: So you are saying, that there is a third tables which is mapping the relation between the department and the organisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the HQL/JPQL would be:

```
SELECT d FROM Organization o JOIN o.listOfDepartMents d WHERE d.departmentName LIKE "sa%"
```